# Not working: Giving an empty field a value - php

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

http://pastebin.com/RE31BRSQ

When I do an

```
if ( empty($_POST['name']) ) {
    $name = 'anon'; 
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
}
```

the name is always anon, even if someone enters characters in the field.

Also,

```
if ( empty($_POST['title']) ) {

} else {
    $title = sha1( $_POST['title'] );
}
```

How can I make it so there is a `!` inserted infront of `['title']`?

Comment: What do you see when you do `$_POST['name']`?

Comment: I was about to say, could we see the code for the form itself?

Comment: try to debug post array like this print_r($_POST);

Comment: when I do $_POST['name'] without the if statement it gives me whatever the user typed in. the else part makes the name 'anon' even if the user types something in.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CxNTrUuY  <- form code and this is the site http://www.vidyasocks.com/forums.php?id=2&id=2

Comment: Probably unrelated but you have `name` attribute repeated for input field `name` like this: `<input name="name" title="Name" name="name"  />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Are you really sure that your input field is named `name`?
I would also suggest to use `isset()`:

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) )
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
}
else
{
  $name = 'anon';
}
```

2.) Use the concatenation operator (if you want to prepend all titles with a `!` before hashing):

```
$title = sha1( '!'.$_POST['title'] );
```

Comment: Thank you, I find it strange that the name one didn't work for me before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't depend on `empty()`. It can turn around and bite you. Note that things like `0` are [considered](http://php.net/empty) "empty", even though any sane person wouldn't.

I can't see anything wrong with your first sample, so make sure that your form's 'name' field is actually called 'name'. Those keys are case sensitive, so `$_POST['Name']` is something completely different from `$_POST['nAmE']`.

As for your second example, if you mean `!` as in the "not" operator, you'd do it as

```
if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
   ...
}
```